# Is a correct YAML file enough for a correct ansible playbook, syntax errors aside?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I have an ansible playbook which raises an error (with a dreadful message, as usual):

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to have been in '/root/myplaybook.yml': line 17, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

# configure rsyslog
- name: configure rsyslog to expose events on port 42000
  ^ here
```

The line in question is typical of other lines I have in this and other playbooks:

```
# prepare environment
# configure rsyslog
- name: configure rsyslog to expose events on port 42000
  lineinfile:
    - create: yes
    - dest: /etc/rsyslog.d/expose-42000.conf
    - line: "*.* @127.0.0.1:42000"
  notify:
    - restart rsyslog
```

The file is validated by three online checkers, so there are no YAML errors. **Is this fact enough for the file to be a correct ansible playbook?**

What I am trying to understand is whether a correct YAML file leaves me only with ansible syntax errors (a module which does not exist for instance) or is a playbook an extension of YAML (in the sense that a line like `- name: blah blah blah`is OK from a YAMl perspective, but will be rejected by ansible because (I am making up an example) it has more than two words.

In other words I am checking if the following can be true: the YAML syntax is OK, the ansible keywords are OK but ansible does not conform to YAML syntax fully by having some limitations.

***EDIT***: I had an error, spotted by Konstantin in his answer. 
I will leave this question in place since it helped me to understand that ansible does not put constraints on the YAML file itself, so when there is an error and the validation goes though I am really left with specific ansible syntax errors (or logical, like in my case).

Comment: Your question at the end does not make sense given your Ansible is not ok and Ansible does use YAML syntax. Could you clarify it?

Comment: @MattSchuchard: I am glad that Konstantin has shown that I have an error and this will help me to go ahead -- my general point was that since the error message points more or less randomly to an "expected parameter type" I was wondering if I am just left with syntax errors (which I indeed had) or if I should also take into account the fact that ansible puts specific contraints on the YAML file itself. The answer appears to be "no" so if the YAML validation goes through I have to look for syntax (or like in my case - rather logic) errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, valid YAML does not necessarily give you a valid Ansible playbook.

The error message is `unexpected parameter type in action`.
So Ansible can't interpret what you want. Specifically:

```
  lineinfile:
    - create: yes
    - dest: /etc/rsyslog.d/expose-42000.conf
    - line: "*.* @127.0.0.1:42000"
```

`create`, `dest` and `line` are parameters of `lineinfile` action, but you try to feed a *list* of three *dicts* into the *lineinfile*, because you prepend each parameter with a dash. This is correct from the YAML syntax perspective, but Ansible can't parse it because you are not supposed to feed lists into actions.

To correct the error, remove dashes before these parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding the error. As for the general question, my understanding is that ansible does not put constraints on the YAML file itself, so when there is an error and the validation goes though I am really left with specific ansible syntax errors (or logical, like in my case)

Comment: Yes, you are right: if YAML syntax is OK, you should carefully search for logical mistakes.